# R and RStudio all of a sudden not found any more

Tags: r

I am using the latest version of R (4.0.3) and RStudio. I quit RStudio after saving the workspace. In parallel I was installing the current version of Latex. All of a sudden, I could not open RStudio. I got the message:`Unable to find an installation of R on the system (which R didn't return valid output); Unable to locate R binary by scanning standard locations`. When typing in R in the terminal to launch R or typing in R --version, I get the message: `Command 'R' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install r-base-core`. This is weird. How this can happen ? What should I do ? Did installing Latex change anything important to disable R and RStudio ? Thanks for any comment.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Which terminal are you referring to? Are you in full control of your machine or does someone else administer it? Since you can't even open R this seems more like a question that's more appropriate for https://superuser.com/ since it's about your system configuration.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I am referring to the Ubuntu's Terminal. I am the only one using the computer, it is a laptop.

Comment: How did you install R originally? Using apt-get or compiling yourself? Have you modified you PATH environment variable? Can you verify that the place you installed R is listed on your PATH? What other specific changes have you made to you computing environments. You mention Latex. What exactly did you do to install that? Normally that shouldn’t interfere with R at all.

Comment: I uninstalled R and reinstalled the new version using apt-get, cleaned up sources.list, which contained instances of the older and new R version, allowing only the new version to appear. But the PATH variable was not changed. And yet everything was working perfectly. The only change I made now is uninstalling the older version of texlive and installing the new one. Here is the issue: I am mirroring from a nearby University. In the terminal even after 7 hours, this process is still running now. Maybe I should kill the process. What do you think ? Now I remained without Latex, R and RStudio.